# Django, javascript, and complex forms

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms, flowchart

I'm building an app in django that lets users create and edit flowcharts for the purpose of process/procedure control. There are three basic models: `Procedure`, `Step`, and `Transition`.

I've created and debugged all the model relationships and through the admin interface and shell, I can create `Procedures` with several `Steps` and `Transitions`. It's functional but not intended for the end user. I need to create a browser-based jgraphical interface.

Enter [visjs](http://visjs.org), a javascript visualization library. Using visjs, I've created a basic block-diagram editor that lets users add/edit/delete nodes and edges (this is my first javascript attempt ever). I can load data from the database and post data back to the database through a couple of custom views and JSON serialization. However, it feels kludgey and hard to maintain. For example, it's not integrated into django's forms framework at all.

At the moment, when submitted, the javascript does the serialization to post JSON data and JSON data only. I'd really like this to be a standard form submission but I can't figure out how to structure the form.

How would you go about building a form to do handle this? I'm basically trying to get my javascript block diagram to *be* the form, if that makes any sense. Is this the use-case for a custom widget?

Another wrinkle here is that the editor needs to create/update/delete the top-level procedure, the steps, and the edges.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a custom widget is what your looking for and would start by learning from examples of other Django apps which do something similar. The project I am currently working on includes the app named [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) which creates a widget around [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/).  I believe it solves a similar problem to yours in the sense that it creates a Django widget from a javascript widget.

Study how they approach a similar problem and see if it helps.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for -- a django encapsulation of a javascript UI element... thank you!